# Article about xss and csrf seems wrong

Tags: cookies, token, xss, csrf

I found this article online about xss and csrf https://www.redotheweb.com/2015/11/09/api-security.html when you scroll all the way down to 'the solution' it tells you to use a token and a session cookie. Below that there is a piece of example code. My question is, when a xss attack happens, the so called hacker could just run that piece of code. Retrive the token from local storage and the cookie will automatically attach. Or am I missing something?

```
authenticate(login, password)
    .then(function(authentication) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', authentication.token); // store token
    })
    .then(getAccounts)
    .then(function(accounts) {
        // display the accounts page
        // ...
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // display error message in the login form
        // ...
    });

/**
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function getAccounts() {
    return fetch('https://api.bobank.com/accounts', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'), // <= include token
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include' // <= include session cookie
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
}
```

My specific question would be is this article wrong. And is there a secure method addressing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and XSS attack can normally do anything the rest of the code can do. It is a common misconception to think that XSS needs to steal the tokens or session cookies to be successful. If you are vulnerable to XSS, that XSS can (as you pointed out) simply exercise the same code, and thus achieve CSRF.